# Google redirect to a page like http://my-website.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#/callback

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, angular2-routing, response.redirect

I have an angular application that I upload to AWS S3, everything works fine with the login page, but when I authenticate with Google I redirect the authentication to `http://my-website.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#/callback` as you see I have to use `/#/` other wise AWS S3 gives an error.

My challenge now is that Google doesn't accept `/#/` in **Authorized redirect URIs**.

[image]

Is there any trick to solve this issue? Google confirmation or any angular configuration.

---

Google error

[image]

Comment: Using the hash symbol `#` in a URI is wrong. Remove it. You might still have a problem with backend code that is generating incorrect URIs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I know, but if I remove it the s3 bucket gives me an error that looks like this `404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: callback`

Comment: The URI is a callback endpoint. You must have code that handles the callback. A bucket will not work for that.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley it wasn't clear in my head, but after a search, I found that solution in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my issue, all I do is configure the redirection in my S3 bucket.

Under **Properties** tab => **Static website hosting section** => choose **Edit**.
Scroll down to the **Redirection rules section** and enter these rules in the text box:

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "my-website.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "307",
            "Protocol": "http",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "#/"
        }
    }
]
```